# Preventing Media Player to play multiple sounds at same time

Tags: android, audio, media-player, playback

How to make the mediaplayer to stop playing sound before playing the next sound. So the sounds won't go through each other?

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hekler);
ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
        mp.seekTo(0);
    }
    else{
        mp.start();
    }
    }

});

 mp2=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.uzi);
 ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
 btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp2.isPlaying()){
            mp2.pause();
            mp2.seekTo(0);
        }
        else{
            mp2.start();
        }
        }

 });
 mp3=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.kalas);
 ImageButton btn3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
 btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp3.isPlaying()){
            mp3.pause();
            mp3.seekTo(0);
        }
        else{
            mp3.start();
        }   
    }
});
 mp4=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.emka);
 ImageButton btn4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
 btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp4.isPlaying()){
            mp4.pause();
            mp4.seekTo(0);
        }
        else{
            mp4.start();
        }   
    }
});
 mp5=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.uzi);
 ImageButton btn5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
 btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp5.isPlaying()){
            mp5.pause();
            mp5.seekTo(0);
        }
        else{
            mp5.start();
        }   
    }


});

 mp6=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sporet); 
 ImageButton btn6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
 btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp6.isPlaying()){
            mp6.pause();
            mp6.seekTo(0);
        }
        else{
            mp6.start();
        }   
    }
});

 }
```

I've tried to stop Mp in every thread but it didn't work. Do I need something else like sound pool or there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use only one instance of MediaPlayer, when you want to play another sound, call sotp, then release, then set the mediaplayer variable to another create instance and play your next sound.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(PlaySound.this, R.raw.mySound);
mp.start();

//then when you want to play another sound

mp.stop();
mp.release();
mp = null;

//then make mp equal another create and play it
```

EDIT: use this code

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hekler);
ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        stopPlaying(mp);
    }
    else{
        mp.start();
    }
    }

});

 }
```

Do that for each of your buttons and define the **stopPlaying** method like so...

```
public void stopPlaying(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
}
```

Comment: How do i determine which button to play it?
Also do I need to put in new brackets?

Comment: @user3013161 Please see my edit for a better idea of how to go about solving your problem